# Jquery UI Draggable overflow issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I am using Jquery UI draggable along with jQsplitter and slimscroll. I am facing one issue.  left side div hides when i am trying to drag (left) to right vice versa.

```
$(".list_panel1 .collapse_content .panel").draggable({
 helper: 'clone',
 handle: '.panel-heading .icon',
 appendTo: 'body',
});
```

[image]

Comment: you'd have better chance to get answers here if you post a code snippet that reproduces the problem

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nkumar2/e2bnuLro/10/  I have added the code snippet. Please check it. Thanks.